# How to get the command line of QGIS algorithm "Merge vector layers"?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, vector, merge, qgis-processing

To insert this function to my program I want to know what is command line executed by the algorithm "Merge vector layers" using QGIS GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you run an algorithm from the Processing Toolbox, you can go to `Processing -> History... -> ALGORITHM` and you'll find the Python command to call the algorithm with the parameters you specified via GUI. For instance:

```py
processing.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers",
                  "/docs/geodata/AMAZONAS.shp;/docs/geodata/PUTUMAYO.shp",
                  "/docs/merged.shp")
```

You would need to import the `processing` module before running the algorithm from the QGIS Python Console:

```py
import processing
processing.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers",
                  "/docs/geodata/AMAZONAS.shp;/docs/geodata/PUTUMAYO.shp",
                  "/docs/merged.shp")
```

It's very helpful to understand the parameters of the algoritm, which you can achieve by following @DIVAD's recommendation.

Comment: I'm searching for a shell command line (like ogr2ogr, grass...). I'v try most of them I didn't find one witch satisfy my needs :( . I want to merge tow vector files (polygons) with keeping the attribute table of the fist one and later dissolve the polygons witch overly

Comment: [Here](http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html) you find how to merge 2 Shapefiles with OGR. However, The PyQGIS command I put in my answer can also run in the OS console, as a standalone script, without opening QGIS GUI. Would be that OK for your use case?

Comment: The purpose is to dissolve polygons from layer1 witch overlap with polygons of layer2 keeping attributes table of layer1 and using a shell command line. can you please help me to do that ?

Comment: @Mounirsky - I would suggest asking a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and expand on the details which you mentioned in your last comment. You should also accept an answer provided to you by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side of the answer you feel solved your initial problem :)

Answer (score 3):

You can find all algorithms by typing `processing.alglist()`.

You want to search for merging layers so type `processing.alglist("merge")`.

Then choose one you need, e. g. `processing.alghelp("qgis:mergevectorlayers")` for more information.

Comment: The purpose is to dissolve polygons from layer1 witch overlap with polygons of layer2 keeping attributes table of layer1 and using a shell command line. can you please help me to do that ?