# Is there a way to merge polygons with the same values in a layer created from gdal.Polygonize()?

Tags: gdal, pyqgis, polygonize

i have a tif file which I polygonized using gdal.Polygonize() method. As a result I got a vector layer with millions of polygons and values from 1 to 255 in the attribute table. Although I don't mind such huge number of polygons I would like to merge those which have the same values in the attribute table. Could you tell me if there is a way to do it programmatically using any GDAL/OGR tools?

[image: I would like to merge such values]

Comment: The gdal_polygonize manual page informs: `This utility creates vector polygons for all connected regions of pixels in the raster sharing a common pixel value.` So what you have now are not-connected polygons (or maybe connected at corners). If you union them you will get multipolygons which may be huge with very many members. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I suppose so. I'll try to union them now, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a "Dissolve polygons" tool.
QGIS by default offers two implementations, one as part of its internal toolset (**QGIS geoalgorithms --> Vector Geometry Tools --> Dissolve** ) and one part of the GDAL/OGR toolset (**GDAL/OGR --> OGR Geoprocessing --> Dissolve Polygons** ).
There's one more in the SAGA toolset as well.

All of them differ slightly in the options they offer, but the GDAL/OGR tool is the most "verbose", allowing a lot of customization. So I'd recommend that for most cases.

If you want to use any of these programmatically, I'd recommend using `processing.runalg()` to run them properly in your script.

Comment: Hm, I found "gdalogr:merge" tool to run with `processing.runlag()` but it seems to be working only to merge rasters. Is it applicable to vectors or I am looking in the wrong direction?

Comment: If you can't see the toolbox, make sure you have that panel enabled (right-click anywhere, tick 'Toolbox'). If you don't know the algorithm name, run the process once from the toolbox. Then go to Processing->History (in the main toolbar at the top) and you can see the full pyqgis call to that algorithm, including all the parameters(!) . The tool I mean is called `gdalogr:dissolvepolygons`

Comment: In addition, check out https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/219036/29005 for how to easily query processing algorithms from a python script/console.

Comment: Yes, I believe it's just what I need. I found the tool you were talking about and manage to use this algorithm in the script. Thank you very much.